# What is the correct way to adjust bootstrap columns to specified widths

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, less

In bootstrap 3.0, assuming you are stuck with a 12 column grid, and you have a 3 column sidebar (col-md-3) and a 9 column main content area (col-md-9) but your sidebar content fills roughly 2 and a half columns of the sidebar width, and you are left with about a 40 pixel gap of white space between your sidebar content and your main content area, what can you do to eliminate this space?

I tried setting a negative margin on the main content area, to attempt to pull it over to the left, but it's not working.

What is the best way to deal with this scenario? I'm sure developers have to deal with this issue all the time, since most designers dont design on a 12 column grid.

Comment: Can you post an example? col-md-9 and col-md-3 are percentage widths which add to 100% so if there is a gutter it is coming from something else (most likely the parent container).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do in this case would be not to use the grid for creating the sidebar. So the sidebar and the content would be your own CSS specifying the width of each, and then on the inside of your content is where you would use the 12 chunk grid system.

Comment: But then how do you handle the other breakpoints, do you need to use custom media queries for each resolution?  It seems like an awful lot of work as opposed to using the grid system.

Comment: Actually yes. If you look at a majority of the bootstrap themes that already exist, they do exactly that. Responsive sites are a lot of work to create, that's why the good responsive themes usually cost a good bit of money